# Why is the last value always missing for the posterior probability distribution using 'bcp' for change point detection?

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian

I am using the bcp package for change point detection and am wondering why the last value of the probability distribution is always "NA". I'm wondering if perhaps the bcp algorithm requires a data point after a particular date in order to provide a value. My study period ends the week of 12-29-2019, and I'm wondering whether or not I need an additional week of data in order to truly capture a study period through the week of 12-29-2019.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated. This has happened any time that I use the bcp function, but I'm including a reproducible example below:

Packages:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(tidyverse)
library(bcp)
```

Pulling sample Google Trends data:

```
data = gtrends('stackoverflow', geo = "US-OR", time = "2018-04-01 2019-12-31")$interest_over_time %>% 
  select(-time:-category)
```

Using bcp package:

```
bcp = bcp(data$hits)
  
prob = bcp$posterior.prob
prob = as.data.frame(prob) 

bcp_dataframe = cbind(data, prob) %>% 
    select(date, prob)
```

Resulting dataframe:

[image]

Comment: I suggest emailing the authors. I couldn't confirm it in the documentation, but my guess is that the posterior probability emitted for timepoint `n` represents the probability of a change between `n` and `n+1`; hence the undefined last entry.